# pandas string remove selective value combination

Tags: pandas, string

Hi I have pandas df with string "1) some text WH-1162" some words: 1011,4; 2) some other text: 1 pc; 3) CBHU8512454, number:2; 8) Code:000;"

I wont to get rid of all combinations like "1)" from string but keep other numbers. How can I make it selective so that code recognizes combination to remove

I did not find any workable solution

Comment: Could you give an example of your data and desired output?

Comment: I have 2 million rows of data like "1) Фломастер 12-цветный ""No.858"" 7200 пачках, в кат. кор.: вес: 360 кг, кол. 7200 шт; 2) Вид и количество упаковки:30 коробках;3) № конт.:CBHU8512453 часть, кол-во:1;8) Код инвестпрограммы:000;
11) Признак госзакупок:02;" the desired output is I have 2 million rows of data like "Фломастер 12-цветный ""No.858"" 7200 пачках, в кат. кор.: вес: 360 кг, кол. 7200 шт; Вид и количество упаковки:30 коробках;№ конт.:CBHU8512453 часть, кол-во:1;Код инвестпрограммы:000; Признак госзакупок:02;" I need to removed all 1) or 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the numbers with round bracket such as 1), 2), ... from a string like this:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace(r'\d\)', '')
```

Comment: It weorked perfectly. Thanks a lot for help